# Showing a decomposition of a topological space is upper semicontinuous

Tags: general-topology

**In the section on quotient spaces,** my text (Willard) defines a decomposition $\mathscr{D}$ of X as a collection of disjoint subsets of X whose union is X. (I consider this to be synonymous with "partition.")

The topology of the decomposition is derived from the topology of X, in that a subset of the decomposition is open iff the union of its elements in X is open.

Additionally, the term "upper semicontinuous" is used to describe a decomposition if, for all open sets U containing an element of $\mathscr{D}$, there is an open set $V\subseteq U$ such that V is a union of elements of $\mathscr{D}$

**I'm supposed to "directly" (presumably, by the definition) show that "the decomposition of the plane into concentric circles about the origin" is upper semicontinuous.**

I should be able to show, that for any open set U containing F (a closed circle centered at the origin, an element of D), there is some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $\bigcup B_{\epsilon_{0}}(x)$ for $x \in F$ (the "open annulus of radius epsilon" around F" must be contained in U. (This would also be the union of elements of D, which I have established earlier and don't wish to write up here since it is obvious.)

If there were no such $\epsilon_0$ then I feel that there would necessarily be some $x \in F$ where, for all $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon(x) \notin U$. However, I know this is expressly not a correct line of reasoning, since it would not work if the set F were a copy of the real line...

My problem: My topology text has not yet covered limits or compactness, and I feel that one or the other of these theories would be necessary to actually establish the claim in the paragraph above. I feel it should establish the existence of such an x on the circle, since the circle is compact.

Is there a different way to show that the open annulus must be contained in U, without resorting to compactness? Hints are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the compactness is needed. Consider an analogous example: the decomposition of $ℝ × ℝ$ into horizontal lines is not upper semicontinous.

Regarding the given example, it is practial to use open “polar rectangles” instead of $B_ε(x)$. By compactness it is possible to cover the circle by finitely many polar rectangles contained in $U$, so there is a nonzero lower bound of thickness.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, the text I am working with has not yet introduced compactness, and it would be silly to expect me to derive compactness and all the associated properties to show this: "My topology text has not yet covered limits or compactness, and I feel that one or the other of these theories would be necessary to actually establish the claim in the paragraph above. I feel it should establish the existence of such an x on the circle, since the circle is compact." I thought of this approach AND your counterexample. I was asking if there was a different one.

Comment: But as I demonstrated by the analogous example, the compactness is needed here. You need that every open cover of a circle has a finite subcover, which easily follows from the same propery of closed interval, and that can be proved directly – it is called Borel or Lebesgue covering theorem.

Comment: I recognize compactness is needed as a property of the set. I was wondering if there was a way to approach the proof that uses the compactness without me needing to derive compactness and all of the ideas. I suppose I could simply prove that an open cover of a closed, bounded subset of R^n can be reduced to a finite subcover, but still. (I'm irked at the text for asking for this here instead of in a few chapters)

Comment: As I said, you need this just for a closed interval. For example, in our first year analysis course, we had this theorem that a closed interval is compact without using the name “compactness” at all.

Comment: "Closed and bounded" is easy enough. I wondered if there was a way to approach this without invoking finite subcovers, but I don't think there is.

Comment: But finite subcovers is what you need in the proof, and proving that every open cover of a closed interval has finite subcover directly is easier than proving that being closed and bounded implies compactness.