# topology quotient and upper semicontinuous sets.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, quotient-spaces

let $D$  be the decopomsition of the plane into concentric circles about the origin.

i need to demonstrate that $D$ is homeomorphic to $A$={$x\in \mathbb R$ :$x\geq$ 0} and $D$ is upper semicontinuous.

this is what i did to demonstrate.

let $P$ the natural map ($P:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow D$) by letting $P(x)$, for $x\in\mathbb R^2$ be the element of $D$ containing $x$

note: the topology the  descomposition sapace $D$ is the quotient topology induced by $P$

let $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow A $, $f(x,y)=x²+y²$.   (we notice that $f$ is surjective), then we endow $A$ with the quotient topology induced by $f$.

so we have to ,  there is a homeomorphism $H:A\longrightarrow D$ , and it is also fulfilled $P= H\circ f$ (*).

To prove that $D$ is upper semicontinuous.this is what i did to demonstrate.

consider the theorem:

the natural map $P$ associated with a decomposition space $D$ of $X$ is closed iff $D$ is upper semicontinuous.

$P= H\circ f$ is closed because $H ,f$ are map closed

the theorem used in(*) is as follows:

if $Y$ has the quotient topology induced by $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to the descomposition space $D$ whose element are the sets $f^{-1}(y), y\in Y $ , under a homeomorphism $H:Y\longrightarrow D$ such that  $P= H\circ f$.

is my reasoning okay?.

any suggestion or contribution is welcome!!

If someone knows how to demonstrate it in another way, I would appreciate it.

the definition of upper semicontinuous ,that is known is:

An open set $V$ in a topological space $X$ is saturated relative to a give decomposition $D$ of $X$ iff $V$ is a union of elements of $D$ (i.e iff $V=P^{-1}(W)$ for some open set $W$ in $D$). A decomposition $D$ is upper semicontinuous iff for each $F\in D$ and each open set $U$ in $X$ containing $F$, there is some saturated open set $V$ in $X$ with $F\subset V\subset U$

Comment: I think your solution is ok, however I'm not sure about the 'upper semicontinuous' part. How is that related to a real valued function $f$ being upper semicontinuous ($x\to a+0\implies f(x)\to f(a)$)?

Comment: When you refer to how the real variable function that I consider in the test is related, do you mean why would I consider that function to demonstrate the second part? .

Comment: For a direct proof using compactness of the elements of $D$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365363/showing-a-decomposition-of-a-topological-space-is-upper-semicontinuous) and its answer.